# Level of coding in Editable PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, formula, calculation

I have to build some formulae in editable PDF, so when some input is keyed in some values are automatically calculated(Basic Maths such as addition/subtraction). I am not sure if this possible?

My lead thinks we can do it using Java script. As one of the limitation is  Client-side JavaScript does not allow the reading or writing of files. This
has been kept for security reason.

Any inputs are much appreciated.

Comment: If writing/reading files would not be allowed, what exactly would you do with the pdf? Where would it come from? I think you have to be a bit more specific and give more details for anyone to help you.

Comment: A PDF can be "editable" and smart if it is using the Forms features. Acrobat JavaScript allows any kind of calculations possible using JavaScript. Note: Reading and Writing files is not done using Acrobat JavaScript (it is possible, but requires higher privileges). These actions are done by the PDF Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an option to custom calculate on editable PDF.

Tools(Usually on the right) -> Forms -> Edit ->

This will list all the forms in the editable PDF.

1) Select a form that needs calculation. 
2) Right click for properties. 
3) select Calculate tab.
4) Add formula